# How to save sparse matrix into hive table by pyspark

Tags: python, hive, pyspark, scipy

I have a rdd, which every row contain three data type. For example

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField,FloatType,IntegerType,ArrayType

# create sparse matrix
row = np.array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
col = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2])
data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
sp_mat = csc_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(3, 3))

# create rdd
sqlContext = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
sp_data = [(0,12.1,sp_mat),(1,21.32,sp_mat),(2,21.2,sp_mat)]
spare_rdd = sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(sp_data)
print(spare_rdd.take(3)) 

# print
[(0, 12.1, <3x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>' with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>)
,(1, 21.32, <3x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>' with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>)
,(2, 21.2, <3x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>' with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>)]
```

The first two data types are int and float. The three data types is scipy sparse matrix. I want to write this rdd data to hive table. But I don't know what form or field to save sparse matrix.

So my questions are as follows：

1. How to create hive table for scipy sparse matrix?

   ```
   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE spare_table(
     id int,
     value float,
     ...  <---- One or more field or struct for scipy sparse matrix 
   )
   stored as orc tblproperties ("orc.compress"="SNAPPY");
   ```
2. How to save scipy sparse matrix into above table by pyspark? If I convert rdd to dataframe by `df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(spare_rdd, schema=['id', 'value', 'scipy'])` will show error:

   > TypeError: not supported type: <class 'scipy.sparse.csc.csc_matrix'>

The solution don't store scipy type are also acceptable. The only requirement is that the solution can support sparse matrix writing and reading again. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at `sparse.save_npz` to see how it saves a sparse matrix to a `numpy` `npz` archive file.  That will show what arrays have to be saved; and `load_npz` recreates a matrix.  You could save the 3 arrays that you used to create `sp_mat` in the first place.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you for your comment. I will try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I can store `indices`,`indptr`,`data` and `shape` of scipy sparse matrix into hive table to achieve it. And I can recreate a sparse matrix based them when I read from hive table again.
First I should create a hive table as follows:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE spare_table(
  id int,
  value float,
  indices array<int>,
  indptr array<int>,
  data array<int>,
  shape array<int>
)
stored as orc tblproperties ("orc.compress"="SNAPPY");
```

Then I convert rdd to dataframe by decomposing scipy sparse matrix into `indices`,`indptr`,`data` and `shape`.

```
grid_img_df = spare_rdd.map(lambda x: [
    x[0]
    ,x[1]
    ,x[2].indices.tolist()
    ,x[2].indptr.tolist()
    ,x[2].data.tolist()
    ,[int(shape) for shape in x[2].shape]])

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(grid_img_df, schema=['id','value','indices','indptr','data','shape'])
df.show()
+---+-----+------------------+------------+------------------+------+
| id|value|           indices|      indptr|              data| shape|
+---+-----+------------------+------------+------------------+------+
|  0| 12.1|[0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2]|[0, 2, 3, 6]|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|[3, 3]|
|  1|21.32|[0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2]|[0, 2, 3, 6]|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|[3, 3]|
|  2| 21.2|[0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2]|[0, 2, 3, 6]|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|[3, 3]|
+---+-----+------------------+------------+------------------+------+
```

Finally, I write it in hive.

```
df.registerTempTable("df_table")
sqlContext.sql(""" INSERT overwrite TABLE spare_table 
                    select id
                            ,value
                            ,indices
                            ,indptr
                            ,data
                            ,shape
                            from df_table""")
```

The code for reading data from the hive table and converting it to scipy sparse matrix is as follows:

```
rdd = df.rdd.map(lambda row:(row.id,row.value,csc_matrix((row.data,row.indices,row.indptr),shape=row.shape)))
```